# How to hide and show another div when I click first div in server side html coding using append

Tags: javascript, web-services, append, server-side, stringbuilder

I have two `<div>` in server side web service page. If I click the first div, the first div should be hidden and second div should be visible. How to hide the first div and show second div using onclick div in server side web service page.

**Javascript**

```
function switchVisible() {
    if (document.getElementById('hidediv')) {
        if (document.getElementById('hidediv').style.display == 'none') {
            document.getElementById('showdiv').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('showdiv').style.display = 'none';
        }
     else {
            document.getElementById('hidediv').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('showdiv').style.display = 'block';
          }
     }
}
```

**HTML**

```
sbBuilder.Append("<div href='#' id='" + "' onclick=" + '"' + "javascript:return ")                
sbBuilder.Append("</div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

just replace the first line of if condition with
if (document.getElementById('hidediv').style.display!== 'none')